# cant select paired bluetooth speaker on Debian 9 - gnome

Tags: debian, bluetooth, speakers, debian-stretch

I have a paired bluetooth speaker (via gnome) ; But it is not proposed in the devices list in the sound configuration...

I really dont know where to look to understand what seems to be the problem ; any help would be appreciated !

Cheers !